# What is proper way to serialize different kinds of model instances in Django (including both primary and foreign keys)

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I want attributes from two different `models.py` `classes` (relations), say `user_name` and `user_workpace_key` form `User` table and `user_workspace_name` from `UserWorkspace` table.

Here, `user_workpace_key` is foreign key. This fields will be of the form `list` since I use `values_list()` method to extract them. The next step is to combine these two lists and use serializer so that I can prepare a `json` out of it. The problem I faced here is, `Django's` default serializer does not support this. It does not allow to concatenate different kinds of model instances together (hence one json cannot be formed).

#### example code:

```
#Fields from `User` table in `models.py`
user_list = user_object.values_list('user_name','user_workpace_key','user_role')
#Fields from UserWorkspace table in models.py
user_workspace_details_list = User_ws_object.values_list('user_workspace_name ','user_workpace_key')
#need to do something like this and make a json of f1 and f2
f1 = serializers.serialize('json', list(user_object), fields = ('user_name','user_workpace_key','user_role'))
f2 = serializers.serialize('json', list(User_ws_object), fields = ('user_workspace_name','user_workpace_key'))
#Here, I am using UUID (default implementation) field of Django 1.8 .
#If I try this, json.dumps(list(user_workspace_list)), 
#it shows error as :"UUID is not JSON serializable".
```

So, the problem is to have a `serializer` that supports the `UUID` and allow me to combine different types of model instances together (so as to form a `json`). Kindly suggest me what to do to solve this problem. Other than `Django's` default `serializers`, are there any other alternatives available? Or what is the method that allow `UUID` in default serilizer only??

Please Help.

Comment: I assume you have spotted [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: Take a look ot Django Rest Framework [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), they will help you to create a desired json structure. About the `UUID` field read [here](http://arthurpemberton.com/2015/04/fixing-uuid-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: thanks.. I am trying this solution.